# Authenticating to jenkins with python3 requests module

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, jenkins, python-requests

I have the following problem:

I get the status and some other information from a jenkins server via a curl right now and everything works fine and I get the information. Now I wanted to exchange
the way of how to get it to the requests lib and now I can not get to authentificate anymore. I use the following right now for the request part:

```
data ={"Username":"foo_user","Password":"bar_pass"}        
response = session.post("jenkins_url_to_trigger",data=data )
```

Also I tried to set the auth parameter with http basic auth.

If anyone was able to access a jenkins server via the requests lib it would be
nice to see a example of how to do it, since i'm stuck at it now for a while.

Also for the curl part which works I use the following simple syntax:

```
curl -u foo_user:bar_pass -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" jenkins_url/something/to/get/api/json --insecure
```

Also I searched for similar questions and didn't find anything that did help me.

Answer (score 1):

Supply the credentials in a tuple as `auth` instead of in a dictionary as `data`.

```
credentials = ('foo_user', 'bar_pass')       
response = session.post('<jenkins_url_to_trigger>', auth=credentials)
```

See [Authentication](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/authentication/).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the auth in the `requests.Session` object

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
session.auth = ('myuser', 'mypass')

resp = session.post('jenkins_url_to_trigger')
```

`Session` object reference: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects